# Openstack pike and ceph luminous - InvalidArgumentError

Tags: openstack, ceph

currently we are about to set up an openstack pike with cheph luminous.

As connecting to cinder, the following error appears:

```
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/manager.py", line 430, in init_host
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager          self.driver.check_for_setup_error()
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File     "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/drivers/rbd.py", line 267, in check_for_setup_error
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager     with RADOSClient(self):
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/drivers/rbd.py", line 149, in __init__
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager     self.cluster, self.ioctx = driver._connect_to_rados(pool)
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/drivers/rbd.py", line 325, in _connect_to_rados
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager     return _do_conn(pool, remote, timeout)
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/utils.py", line 799, in _wrapper
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager     return r.call(f, *args, **kwargs)
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/retrying.py", line 206, in call
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager     return attempt.get(self._wrap_exception)
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/retrying.py", line 247, in get
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager     six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/retrying.py", line 200, in call
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager     attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/drivers/rbd.py", line 316, in _do_conn
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager     client.connect()
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "rados.pyx", line 875, in rados.Rados.connect (/build/ceph-12.2.1/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/pybind/rados/pyrex/rados.c:10947)
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "rados.pyx", line 454, in rados.make_ex (/build/ceph-12.2.1/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/pybind/rados/pyrex/rados.c:3319)
2017-10-10 17:41:04.570 13878 ERROR cinder.volume.manager TypeError: InvalidArgumentError does not take keyword arguments
```

We are not aware of what this even means.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

turns out, there was a typo during the auth get-or-create step -.-